# Grant temporary SSH access for support

Tags: ssh, security, remote

I have to provide some user support for a specific software. As providing support via email back-and-forth is tedious, I would like to get temporary access to the user's account.

Let's call the user I am giving support to Bob. Is the following procedure valid?

- Email Bob my public SSH key `id_rsa.pub`
- Then, Bob creates a back-up of `authorized_keys`
- Bob then adds my public SSH key to `authorized_keys` via `cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys`
- I log-in via SSH as user Bob without the need to know Bob's password
- After I have finished troubleshooting and logged out, Bob reverts to his old `authorized_keys`, thus revoking my SSH access

---

**Side question**: How can Bob monitor what I am doing? Since granting me access to his user account requires a lot of trust on Bob's part, transparency would likely boost acceptance of this measure.

---

For the sake of completeness, here is how I tested the procedure at home.

- I email Bob my public SSH key `id_rsa.pub`
- Bob adds `screen -x shared` to his `.bashrc`
- Bob starts a screen session with `screen -d -m -S shared` and attaches to it
- Then, Bob creates a back-up of `authorized_keys`
- Bob adds my public SSH key to `authorized_keys` via `cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys`
- Bob informs me to get going
- I log-in via SSH as user Bob without the need to know Bob's password. I am automatically attached to the already running screen session, thus Bob can monitor my operations
- After I have finished troubleshooting and logged out, Bob reverts to his old `authorized_keys`, thus revoking my SSH access
- Bob can now close all screen sessions and remove the one line he added to  his `.bashrc`

---

**Requirements on Bob's part**:

- A running SSH server
- screen has to be installed

Both tools are available from your Linux distribution's package repositories. As communication is done directly between me and Bob I consider this solution superior to the TeamViewer approach mentioned in the comments. Furthermore, TeamViewer is not open source.

Comment: there are tools like team viewer that allow sharing of screen/shell. 1) bob start TV, 2) bob send id 3) you connect 4) bob see what you are doing.

Comment: Why not 1) Bob changes their password to a temporary one. 2) you log in with that password and fix stuff. 3) You log out and Bob changes their password to previous/new password again?

Comment: @Mioriin because passwords are insecure. Using keys is recommended everywhere.

Comment: I have edited the order of operations, because the keys must be copied AFTER attaching to the screen session, to avoid leaving an unmonitored window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure is fine. Bob can either edit your key out or restore the backup. Consider the possibility that `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` does not exist.

To monitor what someone is doing in the shell I would use `screen`.

1. Bob adds `screen -R` to .bashrc
2. You land in a screen session when logging in. Bob can see everything you type in the screen session.

(I am remembering the screen commands by hearth and some more config or test is probably needed. Check this documentation out http://wiki.networksecuritytoolkit.org/index.php/HowTo_Share_A_Terminal_Session_Using_Screen)

Comment: Good tip regarding `screen`, I have to check this one out.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "probably negligible" chain of trust problem with emailing Bob the public key.  **Bob cannot confirm your identity through standard email, since spoofed emails can be produced by an attacker**.  I say "probably negligible" because I am assuming there is not an attacker specifically targeting you as a large corporate enterprise, who is trying to generate fictitious traffic.  In short there are easier scams.  However there is technically a problem with your protocol.

If the email is signed using S/MIME to confirm that the message originated from your domain, or with a pre shared PGP then this is not a problem.

If you don't want to go to the trouble with email, you should host the public key on your website over **HTTPS** so that Bob can download the key himself.  **Then direct Bob to obtain the key from the website to ensure security.**